# RavenDB HTTP API Metadata all documents

Tags: api, http, metadata, ravendb

is there a url which when called on the http api would return the metadata for all documents contained in the DB?
I know I can get it for one type / doc but don;t know how to do it for all types.
Scott

Answer (score 1):

You can call `/docs` to get all documents.  If you just want the metadata, there is a querystring parameter for that:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/docs/?metadata-only=true
```

[Documentation Here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api/extensions/metadata-only)